# Dimension of $K\subset L(\alpha)$ where $L$ is a field extension of $K$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $L$ is a field extension of $K$ and $\alpha$ an element in a field extension of $L$. Can we say $[K\colon L(\alpha)]=[K\colon K(\alpha)]$? I tried to prove this, but I couldn't come up with a proof. I need hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general, take $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$.

By tower law, we can say $[K:L(\alpha)]=[K:L][L:L(\alpha)]$ or $[K:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):L(\alpha)]$, which may or may not be useful depending on what you know about $K,L$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. The original exercise was actually to show that $[K(\alpha):K]\geq [L(\alpha):L]$. If $[K:L(\alpha)]=[K:K(\alpha)]$ then I would be done already! Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Badshah Sure, the degree of $[F(\alpha):F]$ for any field $F$ is the degree of the minimum polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$. If $K \subset L$ what can you say about the minimum polynomials of $\alpha$ over $K$ and over $F$?

Comment: Intuitively I would say that the degree of the minimum polynomial $f_K$ of $\alpha$ in $K$ is higher than the degree of the minimum polynomial $f_L$ of $\alpha$ in $L$, because in $L$ the polynomial $f_K$ maybe can be factored such that $f_K=f_L\cdot h$ for some polynomial $h$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Badshah Yes, exactly. The fact that $K \subset L$ means that $f_K \in L[X]$ and since $f_K(\alpha)=0$, by definition of minimal polynomial (or by using division algorithm) $f_L | f_K$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

It is true only if
$$
[K(\alpha):L(\alpha)]=1,
$$
or equivalently
$$
K(\alpha)=L(\alpha),
$$
since
$$
[K:L(\alpha)]=[K:K(\alpha)]\,[K(\alpha):L(\alpha)].
$$